# How to preserve spaces in multiline string for helm value with cdktf

Tags: javascript, typescript, terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-cdk

I'm using CDKTF to deploy the datadog helm chart into a kubernetes cluster. I'm trying to set a value for confd but the spaces in my typescript multiline string aren't being preserved. Here's how I'm setting the confd value in typescript

```js
    new helm.Release(this, "datadog-agent", {
      chart: "datadog",
      name: "datadog",
      repository: "https://helm.datadoghq.com",
      version: "3.1.3",
      set: [
        {
          name: "clusterAgent.confd",
          value: `postgres.yaml: |-
cluster_check: true
init_config:
instances:
\t- dbm: true
\t  host: <redacted>
\t  port: 5432
\t  username: datadog
\t  password: <redacted>
    `
        }

      ],
    });
```

however, when I try to deploy this I see the following diff

```
                   + set {
                   + name  = "clusterAgent.confd"
                   + value = <<-EOT
                   postgres.yaml: |-
                   cluster_check: true
                   init_config:
                   instances:
                   - dbm: true
                   host: <redacted>
                   port: 5432
                   username: datadog
                   password: <redacted>

                   EOT
```

which makes it seem like all the spaces and tabs in the multiline string are being stripped.

How can I get CDKTF to preserve the spaces in my multiline string?

Comment: Have you considered reading the values file locally?

Comment: I have but ran into other issues with that. I'm open to literally any solution. Here's the SO post I made about the issue with reading the value file locally (assuming I understand you correctly): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73833680/how-to-load-local-file-with-cdktf-for-helm-release

Comment: I'll answer your other question with an example.

Comment: You're a hero! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

While it's a bit hacky you could try to use something like this:

```
value: `postgres.yaml: |- ${
  Fn.base64decode(
    Buffer.from(
`cluster_check: true
init_config:
instances:
\t- dbm: true
\t  host: <redacted>
\t  port: 5432
\t  username: datadog
\t  password: <redacted>`
    ).toString('base64')
  )
}
`
```

Where is Fn is imported from cdktf. The Fn function is executed at runtime, so during synth time you have your base64 encoded content which is safe from any manipulation that cdktf might accidentally do here.